# How to pivot multiple columns in BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

i want to pivot multiple metrics in a table. how to write the syntax to achieve the following?

**current table**

```
date          iso_week          iso_year          metric1         metric2
2021-12-01       48              2021              1000             500
2021-11-30       48              2021               850             300
...
2020-11-28       48              2020               800             400
2020-11-27       48              2020               950             450
...
2019-11-27       48              2019               700             350
2019-11-26       48              2019               820             380
```

**desired output**

```
iso_week          metric1_thisYear        metric1_prevYear       metric1_prev2Year       metric2_thisYear        metric2_prevYear        metric_prev2Year
48                     1850                   1750                   1520                   800                   950                   730
```

...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select * except(date)
  from your_table
)
pivot (sum(metric1) as metric1, sum(metric2) as metric2 for iso_year in (2021, 2020, 2019))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: glad it worked for you. consider also voting up the answer if it really helped

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with the syntax as the big query documentation was somewhat lacking for multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to summarize the metrics of the year that you have grouped these metrics: by year and week. Then, there are two approaches that bring the desired output that you want.

At the first approach, I only group the year and the week once, but I need to have multiple SELECT in order to do this as the desired output.

```
With Datat as(
   SELECT '2021-12-01' as date, 48 as iso_week, 2021 as iso_year, 1000 as metric1, 500 as metric2 union all
   SELECT '2021-11-30' as date, 48 as iso_week, 2021 as iso_year, 850 as metric1, 300 as metric2 union all
   SELECT '2020-12-01' as date, 48 as iso_week, 2020 as iso_year, 800 as metric1, 400 as metric2 union all
   SELECT '2020-12-01' as date, 48 as iso_week, 2020 as iso_year, 950 as metric1, 450 as metric2 union all
   SELECT '2019-12-01' as date, 48 as iso_week, 2019 as iso_year, 700 as metric1, 350 as metric2 union all
   SELECT '2019-12-01' as date, 48 as iso_week, 2019 as iso_year, 820 as metric1, 380 as metric2
),
data2 as(
select iso_week, iso_year, sum(metric1) as metric1, sum(metric2) as metric2 from Datat GROUP BY iso_year, iso_week
)
select iso_week, (select d2.metric1 from data2 d2 where d2.iso_year=2021 ) as metric1_thisyear, (select d2.metric1 from data2 d2 where d2.iso_year=2020 ) as metric1_prevyear, (select d2.metric1 from data2 d2 where d2.iso_year=2019 ) as metric1_prev2year,
(select d2.metric2 from data2 d2 where d2.iso_year=2021 ) as metric2_thisyear, (select d2.metric2 from data2 d2 where d2.iso_year=2020 ) as metric2_prevyear, (select d2.metric2 from data2 d2 where d2.iso_year=2019 ) as metric2_prev2year
from data2 d2 group by iso_week
```

At the second approach, I group the week only because I filter the year at the subquery. This consumes less slot time; it looks like this:

```
With Datat as(
   SELECT '2021-12-01' as date, 48 as iso_week, 2021 as iso_year, 1000 as metric1, 500 as metric2 union all
   SELECT '2021-11-30' as date, 48 as iso_week, 2021 as iso_year, 850 as metric1, 300 as metric2 union all
   SELECT '2020-12-01' as date, 48 as iso_week, 2020 as iso_year, 800 as metric1, 400 as metric2 union all
   SELECT '2020-12-01' as date, 48 as iso_week, 2020 as iso_year, 950 as metric1, 450 as metric2 union all
   SELECT '2019-12-01' as date, 48 as iso_week, 2019 as iso_year, 700 as metric1, 350 as metric2 union all
   SELECT '2019-12-01' as date, 48 as iso_week, 2019 as iso_year, 820 as metric1, 380 as metric2
),
data2 as(
select iso_week, sum(metric1) as metric1, sum(metric2) as metric2 from Datat  where Datat.iso_year =2021 GROUP BY iso_week
),
data3 as(
select iso_week, sum(metric1) as metric1, sum(metric2) as metric2 from Datat  where Datat.iso_year =2020 GROUP BY  iso_week
),
data4 as(
select iso_week, sum(metric1) as metric1, sum(metric2) as metric2 from Datat  where Datat.iso_year =2019 GROUP BY  iso_week
)
select d2.iso_week, d2.metric1, d3.metric1 as metric1_prevyear, d4.metric1 as metric1_prev2year,
d2.metric2, d3.metric2 as metric2_prevyear, d4.metric2 as metric2_prev2year  
from data2 d2 join data3 d3 on d2.iso_week =d3.iso_week  join data4 d4 on d3.iso_week=d4.iso_week
```

[image]