# Bigquery: To convert rows(on groupby) to columns in bigquery w.r.t. row value

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, transpose

Have got a table data like below (sample data provided for single store, this data repeats for multiple store)
[image]

Need to convert/transpose above table to below format in bigquery
[image]

Comment: below seems to be helpful for your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70380324/how-to-pivot-multiple-columns-in-bigquery-standard-sql

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement you can consider using [PIVOT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator) operator.

For example:

```
select * from (
  select * except(category)
  from `projectId.dataset.table`
)
pivot (sum(sales) as sales,sum(item_sold) as item_sold for (type) in ('Loose','PP'))
```

Output:

[image]

But using pivot, as per your requirement it's not possible to return a column as `sales PP fruit`. When using a single PIVOT column we can only include one `for` condition.

To pivot multiple column you need to use Muliple Pivot's.You can refer to this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707421/sqlserver-multiple-pivot-on-same-columns/27708791#27708791).